# apt-get update errors - 50unattended-upgrades.ucf-dist

Tags: apt, updates

I am getting a few errors when doing `apt-get update`. Some seem fatal, some are just ignored, but anyway I want to remove them to prevent further issues.

It was working until I added:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:scribus/ppa
```

The first error is:

```
N: Ignoring file '50unattended-upgrades.ucf-dist' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
```

This does not seem to cause issues, as saw it before.  But, it still appears each time.

The second error is:

```
W: chmod 0700 of directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (1: Operation not permitted)
```

One last error is:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
```

There are other errors, but I will list them once I correct these.

Comment: You should use http://pastebin.com, and post all of the output as is, without any kind of editing. Anyway, the first one is obvious, it should be `50unattended-upgrades` without that stuff at the end.

Comment: 'permission denied' usually means you ran the command without sudo.

Comment: OK, the sudo addition helped.  Thanks.  Iforgot..    I did add the full new text from the sudo apt-get update:  http://pastebin.com/w9se5LG3       I still seem to get the first error that I got last time.

Answer (score 7):

Just remove it is unnecessary:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades.ucf-dist
```